# Masking the URL in Spring MVC

Tags: html, spring-mvc

In our project we were using Frames.Now we upgraded to HTML 5 where frames are deprecated.
Also we are using SPRING MVC. Earlier because of Frame user was not able to see the total URL, also when user copy link to the other tab/browser, he was redirected to the login page. But now, by using Spring MVC which is more a URL based request mapping framework and by using HTML 5, we are unable to achieve the functionality.

Is there any way to **redirect it back to Lo-gin page**, if user types in any URL in another tab/browser.

Is there any to **mask the URL** such that user will able to see only the host and port.

Help is deeply appreciated.

Comment: You can try implementing a single entry filter extending the Spring's OncePerRequestFilter instead of masking the URL, take a look at the following link http://krams915.blogspot.com.es/2010/12/spring-security-mvc-implementing-single.html, maybe this helps you.

Comment: Thanks,Just have a look at it. Look's good while reading. Will let u know once i implement the functionality.

Answer (score 0):

If you convert all your web action to AJAX, url won't show up on browser bar.  However they could still snoop with simple javascript debugger tool.